# Sum of Littlewood-Richardson coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

(Asked first in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4370857/sum-of-littlewood-richardson-coefficients))

Let $c_{\lambda\mu}^\nu$ be the usual Littlewood-Richardson coefficients, which appear for example in the expansion of a product of Schur polynomials into Schur polynomials,
$$ s_\lambda(x)s_\mu(x)=\sum_\nu c_{\lambda\mu}^\nu s_\nu(x).$$

My question is what is known about the sum
$$ \sum_\mu c_{\lambda\mu}^\nu$$

I am specially interested in the case when $\nu$ and $\lambda$ have the same Durfee square.

Comment: Any skew shape $\nu/\lambda$ can be written as a skew shape $\rho/\sigma$ where $\rho$ and $\sigma$ have the same Durfee square, so you gain nothing from this assumption.

Comment: @RichardStanley I don't understand. If $\nu$ and $\lambda$ have the same Durfee square, this means $\nu/\lambda$ is disconnected, no? But not all skew shapes are disconnected.

Comment: One of the components of $\nu/\lambda$ can be empty. E.g., $(2)$ and $(1)$ have the same Durfee square, but $2/1$ is connected.